# How to correctly defines types inside a Dart Map

Tags: flutter, dart

so I am currently learning Dart (Flutter) and I have come to something I can't really understand. So I'm hoping that someone will be able to point out the obvious thing here :)

If I write my code like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: QuizPage(
          title: 'Quiz APP',
          questions: [
            {'question': 'Color?', 'answers': ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Black"]},
            {'question': 'Animal?', 'answers': ["Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Rabbit"]},
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  QuizPage({super.key, required this.title, required this.questions});

  final String title;
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _QuizPageSate();
  }
}
```

It works, but I have later to cast the answers Object with `as List<String>`. However, if I directly define the `questions` type as:

```
final List<Map<String, List<String>>> questions;
```

it will not work and throw an error:

```
The element type 'String' can't be assigned to the map value type 'List<String>'.
```

It seems like it doesn't know how to interpret the type I pass in. Do all non "primitive" types inside a `Map` have to be defined as `Object` or am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you declare the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    'question': 'Color?',
    'answers': [
      "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Black"
    ]
  },
  {
    'question': 'Animal?',
    'answers': [
      "Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Rabbit"
    ]
  },
]
```

This, in Dart, is a `List` of `Map`s, and those maps have a key of `String` and a value of either `String` (the question) or a `List` of `String` (the answers).

The problem is this "either", you cannot have a type of either `String` or `List<String>`, so you have to use `Object` or `dynamic`, which both accept any type.

So, when you used `Object`, it worked because it accepts anything, but you have to cast it correctly later. And when you used `List<String>`, the question ('Color?', 'Animal?'), which is **not** a `List<String>`, stopped being a valid type.

What you can do to avoid dynamic types is to use classes. Make your `QuizPage` accept a `List<QuizQuestion>`, for example.

```dart
class QuizQuestion {
   final String question;
   final List<String> answers;

   QuizQuestion(this.question, this.answers);
}
```

And then do:

```dart
QuizPage(
  title: 'Quiz APP',
  questions: [
    QuizQuestion('Color?', ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Black"]),
    QuizQuestion{'Animal?', ["Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Rabbit"]),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `questions` list first map contain two `key`: `value`. One of the values are `String` and the other is `list`, if you define the value as `dynamic` or `Object` its ok, but if you set it as `list` because of first value it through error.

`Object` or `dynamic` means you don't know the type and every type is accepted.

So the only option you have is cast your `answers` to `List<String>` which you are doing it now.